# Spliting PHP/MySQL data into 3 columns

Tags: php, html

I need to create 3 HTML columns in PHP with data returned from MySQL.  I would like the data split evenly between all 3 columns... How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP/MySQL.  This is an HTML question...

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but presumably the problem is what HTML to generate.

Comment: @Michael, How should it be broken up?  Should items be ordered horizontally, then vertically (first row is 1 2 3, second is 4 5 6), or vertically first (first row is 1 3 5, second is 2 4 6)?

Comment: Using the mans code below I'd like to have it broken up horizontally. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try doing something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table");
$i = 0;
echo '<table><tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
  if ($i++ == 2) echo '</tr><tr>'
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

note this table has the values ordered like

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

If you wanted it vertically like

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Then you should do something like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table");
$data = Array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) $data[] = $row;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) / 3; $i++){

  echo '<table><tr>';

  for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
    echo '<td>' . $data[ $i + $j * 3] . '</td>';
  }

  echo '</tr><tr>'
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: FFS, please stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions and teaching others to do it. -1

Comment: I would normally use PDO but how the data is retrieved isn't the focus of my response.  The question asked how to get data into 3 columns and the approach used can be used regardless of how the resultant rows are obtained

Comment: No problem! :) Glad to be of service

Comment: @tereško, he's cool. I usually use the mysqli functions that come packaged with Ci (CodeIgniter)... So whenever I get code like this, I just port it over.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML table and then use a PHP foreach loop to loop through the MySQL result set and put each field in its own table. At the end of each record returned by the MySQL query, end the table row and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

A small detail, if return more entries than the "fetch_row" use "break", based on the answer from @Robbie: [Spliting mysql data in 3 columns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004477/spliting-mysql-data-in) -3-columns-error