# Spliting mysql data in 3 columns error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Morning,

We have a script for spliting the data we get from a mysql database (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660624/1067100) in a table with three columns, in the case of the current example, we have a database that returns 8 values ​​but appear 9 (latter completely empty).

The current image can clarify the problem if it has become abundantly clear, and also a link to the code we think is wrong. We have reviewed but we are not able to find out what the problem.. :/

the code: https://gist.github.com/99df1288cd1d998c8172

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queickest fix is that you need a "[break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)" in the inner loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data)/3; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++){
         if (($i * 3) + $j >= count($data)) {
             break;
         }
```

Note that you should save a fractional bit of computing power by storing count($data) in a variable - unless you expect the count to change.

```
$countOfData = count($data);
for ($i=0; $i < $countOfData/3; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++){
         if (($i * 3) + $j >= $countOfData) {
             break;
         }
```

Comment: I could not think at any time using "break".. Thanks Robbie:)