# Splitting MySQL results into 3 columns with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to output results from my database into 3 columns (varying numbers of records) but not having any success. I've found a few solutions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660484/spliting-php-mysql-data-into-3-columns) being the closest) but most of them work horizontally with table markup, whereas my markup is already columns.

Code structure as follows:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
        result 1
        result 2
        result 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        result 4
        result 5
        result 6
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        result 7
        result 8
        result 9
    </div>
</div>
```

My current PHP attempt is as follows:

```
echo "<div class='col'>";

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY RAND()");
$resultCount = $result->num_rows;
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

if($i > 0 AND $i % 3 == 0) {
echo "</div><div class='col'>";
}

?>
  <div class="result">
      content here
  </div>
<?php
$i++;
}

echo "</div>";
```

This works with my example of 9 results, but as soon as there's 10 it creates a 4th column which breaks the layout. I can see why, as I'm telling it to end and start a new column every 3 results without stopping.

I know I need to be doing something with the total number of records and splitting that into 3, but that's where I'm stuck. If there's a remainder (e.g. 10) I guess I'd prefer it sits in the first column, so the results set would be split into 4/3/3.

Ideas/suggestions much appreciated!

*Note: I had considered it would be easier to do this with a different HTML structure, but due to the layout it needs to be vertically in columns as the individual results are varying height boxes that can expand/contract, so structurally it needs to stay like this.*

Comment: You want to know how to output an array on a 3 column grid. There's no need to include any sql here.

Comment: I think I would just have a series of li elements, and then use css to do the formatting - with something like masonry/packery (https://packery.metafizzy.co/) in the background - but I don't do much of this kind of thing, so I might be a bit out of touch.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok - given the apparent complexity of what I'm trying to do, it might be best to tackle this from a layout perspective instead. That masonry example looks good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've now found the best solution for this:

1. Save my database query results into an array
2. Use array_chunk to split the results into 3
3. Iterate through each column and each array respectively

Example:

```
<?php

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM stories");
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}            

$lists = array_chunk($rows, ceil(count($rows) / 3));

// You can replace this $column with $grid or $row depending on your use case.
foreach ($lists as $column) {
    echo "<div class='column'>";
        foreach ($column as $item) {                      
            echo $item;
        }
    echo "</div>";
}            

?>
```

Comment: Great answer, I am editing in a semicolon at the end of `echo $item` to prevent a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example. I open a div before the loop and close it after the loop and fill it with 3 rows and close and open again.

Hope it helps.

```
<?php

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY RAND()");
    $resultCount = $result->num_rows;
    $totalCols = 0;
    $out = "<div class='col'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if ($totalCols ==3) {
            $out .= "</div><div>" 
            $out .= $row['col'];
            $totalCols = 1;
        }else{
            $out .= $row['col'];
            $totalCols ++;
        }


    }

$out .= "</div>"; 
print "<div class='grid'> $out </div>" ;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though if I'm understanding correctly, will this just output 3 results per column? The number of results will vary, so I'm looking for it to split the total number across 3 columns which could be any number of results.

Comment: yes, you can replace the 3 for whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Sorry this produces the same issue I have currently - when the results are more it just creates more columns.

Comment: can you post what is your desired result ?

Comment: I've posted the solution now - the desired result was the HTML in my original question, to keep 3 columns and have a varying number of results.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is get the data in the structure you want before you try to echo out any html. Because you will have closed out cols you can't really go back to the first col once you've done this.

Some ways that spring to mind are:

1.Get all the data in a single array (e.g. fetchAll) - I can't remember offhand the Mysqli way to do this (you should be using PDO anyway, but I'll spare you that lecture here) then count the size of the results.  You can then start a new column when you get to a certain point e.g.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
$i++;
    if($i >= sizeof($result)/3){$i = 0; echo '</div>'...}
    ....your Code here
 }
```

You could also split it up into 3 separate arrays and then iterate over each one to get your cols, but that's a lot of loops, so it wouldn't be my preferred way.

2. Get the data in the format you want it to start with eg

   "SELECT IF(id%3 = 0,title,null) AS col_one, IF(id%3 = 1,title,null) AS col_two ... etc

then you will have a result that has three columns anyway and you can either iterate quickly over each column, or use something more attractive like an array map for each one to quickly format it into an html string of li's etc etc

obviously this is not a tutorial on how to do it, but something to point you in a sensible direction.

Also, implant some PDO, people here will get cross with you if you don't (and there's not really an excuse not to be using it)